# Webpack - Failed to generate the compiled files, or even the dist folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I run : `webpack-dev-server`, it compiles code and gives the output in browser.
But when I run : `webpack - p` it did not generate the files in `dist` folder, it did not even create the folder `dist`

Here are the some of files and the directory structure of my project

**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin,{extract} from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import path,{resolve} from 'path';

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname + 'dist'),
        filename : 'app.bundle.js' 
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "css-loader",
                        "sass-loader",
                    ],
                    publicPath: "/dist"
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer:{
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        stats:'errors-only'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Webpack starter project',
            template: './src/index.html',
            hash:true,
            minify:{
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS:true,
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "app.css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: webpack -p assumes that your webpack config is named, ```webpack.config.js``` if you have a different name add the config option https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#configuration-file-config-example-config-js, next time read the docs.

Comment: My wild guess was going to be adjusting `path: resolve(__dirname + 'dist')` to `path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist')`

Answer (score 0):

A normal webpack file wouldn't understand ES6/7 features. So in case if you want to use them inside your webpack configuration, you gotta call the command in the following way as mentioned below.

```
$ webpack -p --config webpack.config.babel.js
```

Comment: replacing `path:resolve(__dirname + 'dist')` with `path: join(__dirname, "dist"),` solved my problem